# Jquery loaded div attribute return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i try to get this attribute from ajax loaded div it return undefined

```
$(document).on('click', '.next', function(e) {
    var vid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log("data-id is " + vid);
  });
```

console return the data-id is undefined

ajax loaded content

```
<div class = 'next' date-id ="21" ><svg></svg> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo mistake :

`$(this).attr('data-id');` to `$(this).attr('date-id');`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.next', function(e) {
    var vid = $(this).attr('date-id');
    console.log("data-id is " + vid);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a typo only?

In JS you're using `data-id` but in html you set `date-id` (See `a` VS `e`).